# Iostat has the value 2 when opening a file

Tags: fortran, gfortran

The compiler is going through without problems but 
`program.exe name_of_data` is throwing: `error in opening file, iostat=2.`
The data is in the same place as the program and in the first row is an integer, the rest are real numbers.

```
program task2a
implicit none
character(len=100) :: dateiname
integer :: ierror, n, read_error
real(kind=8) :: x, sum, average, sd, squaresum
sum=0.0
squaresum=0.0
if (command_argument_count() < 1) then
    write(*,*) " FEHLER : zu wenige Argumente "
    stop
else
    call get_command_argument (1, dateiname)
end if
open(unit=12, file= dateiname, status= 'old', action='read', iostat=ierror)
if (ierror==0) then
    read(12,*, iostat=read_error) n
    if (read_error>0) then
    write(*,*) "error in file"
    stop
    else
        do
            read(12,*,iostat=read_error) x
            if (read_error>0) then
             stop "error in file"
            else if (read_error<0) then
            exit !end of file
            else
                sum= sum +x
                squaresum=squaresum+x**2
            end if
        end do
    end if
else
    write(*,*) "Error: opening file, number:", ierror
    stop
end if
close(unit=12)
average= sum/n
sd=sqrt((squaresum-(sum**2)/n)/(n-1))
write(*,*) "average:", average
write(*,*) "standard deviation:", sd
end program task2a
```

Comment: Does the file exist? is the word `error` with lowercase or uppercase `e` ?

Comment: The output is "Error: opening file, number: 2" and the file exists.

Comment: Looks like there is a problem opening the file. Please write the name of the `dateiname` (to be sure it is the right name). Do you start the program from the command line or through e.g. a double click.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: I start the program in the command line by ```programname dataname```. And program and data are both on the desktop.

Comment: Maybe `open(unit=12, file=trim(dateiname), status= 'old', action='read', iostat=ierror)` ?

Comment: Remove the iostat= thing if all you're doing is stopping when it happens. Then the compiler will print a more informative error message, and stop anyway.

Comment: @janneb, Or add the iomsg= tag to get the message from the OS.

Comment: What is the file name? Does it contain spaces? Can you make the program print the filename before trying to open it?

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to answer the question.

Obviously it's failing to open the file for reading but without more information we will not be able to tell you exactly what is wrong.

Here are some ideas:

- Contrary to your expectation, the program is not executed in the working directory that contains the file.
- The filename contains a space or other special character that causes it to be improperly passed to the program. For example, if the file is called `data file.txt`, then the call

  ```
  $ ./program data file.txt
  ```

  will pass `data` as the first command argument, and `file.txt` as the second.
- The filename is too long. You have given yourself 100 characters length, but if you enter the full path, possibly including unicode characters, it might not be enough.
- The file exists, but you don't have read permissions.

The best way to find out what is happening is to make the program more talkative:

Apart from the `iostat` argument, practically all modern Fortran Compilers (I think it's Fortran 2003 standard) understand the `iomsg` argument:

```
character(len=100) :: io_emsg
...
open(unit=12, file=dateiname, status='old', action='read', &
     iostat=ierror, iomsg=io_emsg)
if (ierror /= 0) then
     print *, "Error opening file ", trim(dateiname)
     print *, trim(io_emsg)
     stop
end if
```

`iomsg` is a string that returns a readable error message.